Functioning of a webpack caching loader
The following text and code block is from SurviveJS book explaining how caching loader works:

Caching with loaders
Although webpack caches loaders by default unless they set this.cacheable(false),
writing a caching loader can be a good exercise as it helps you to understand how
loader stages can work together. The example below shows how to achieve this
(courtesy of Vladimir Grenaderov):

const cache = new Map();
module.exports = function (content) {
    // Calls only once for given resourcePath
    const callbacks = cache.get(this.resourcePath);
    callbacks.forEach((callback) => callback(null, content));
    cache.set(this.resourcePath, content);
    return content;
};
module.exports.pitch = function () {
    if (cache.has(this.resourcePath)) {
        const item = cache.get(this.resourcePath);
        if (item instanceof Array) {
            item.push(this.async()); // Load to cache
        } else {
            return item; // Hit cache
        }
    } else {
        cache.set(this.resourcePath, []); // Missed cache
    }
};


A pitch loader can be used to attach metadata to the input to use later. In this example,
a cache was constructed during the pitching stage, and it was accessed during normal
execution.

It appears that each loader in the webpack loader chain has it's own cache. Is this correct?
If so, then for the given code, we can expect to get cache miss first time for a resourcePath during pitching which will lead to storing empty array for the associated resourcePath key in the cache. Then, during execution stage, I assume that either a callback passed as content or some actual content it set for the same resourcePath key for which miss occurred during pitching. I am not following when does this code actually store callback as part of array to begin with?
